# Neo4j staged batch import

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing

I want to import existing entities and their relationships from MySQL database to a new Neo4j db. I have several questions that I still do not quite understand -

Based on the description of the batch importer, it appears as if I need to have both an entity and relationship file. Can I execute an import without one or the other file type?

Can I execute a series of batch imports, using different files for different entities?

Comment: Fixed it. Please re-download the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the batch importer from the Neo4j website or the one by jexp/Michael Hunger ?

If it's the jexp batch-import you could execute just the entity/nodes file (resulting in a bunch of nodes and no edges) or just the rels file (resulting in an empty graph since there's no nodes to connect). Or you could import the nodes, then import the rels, either in the same import or in a series of imports.

Comment: I am trying to use the one by Michael Hunger. I'm not having much luck with it now.

Comment: What is the issue Mark, the import.bat file?

Comment: Fixed it. Please re-download the zip file.

Comment: Okay, that eliminated the initial error message. However, I keep getting this even after I try to fix the path and classpath variables - The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer